# How to use svg's css hoover like parent

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to create a map to give the Hoover effect.

However, tag text and path cannot be made as parent or child.

```
<svg  viewbox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path  id="CD11110" className="OUTLINE CD11110" d="M 455 297 l 4 -2 1 0 1 0 3 -1 4 5 7 3 2 6 0 8 -11 2 -11 1 -8 0 -9 1 -8 1 -9 1 -9 -2 -10 -1 -9 1 -4 3 -2 3 -6 -6 -3 -4 -5 -6 -4 -5 -2 -5 5 -3 0 -6 0 -10 0 -9 1 -9 -3 -4 -2 0 -2 0 -1 -4 0 -9 -5 -9 1 -10 -1 -11 -1 -6 2 -6 5 -2 7 -3 10 -2 2 -1 3 0 1 0 4 -2 8 -1 3 6 4 1 3 8 3 10 1 6 3 5 0 9 0 7 -1 5 -6 3 -6 4 -1 5 6 4 5 3 5 4 9 1 10 0 4 4 3 4 5 10 1 3 z " />
          <path  id="CD11140" className="OUTLINE" d="M 477 316 l 0 9 5 5 -1 3 -4 5 -4 5 -5 4 -4 7 -3 4 -4 3 -4 10 -2 -1 -3 -7 -2 -5 -2 1 -1 0 -2 -1 -3 1 0 0 -3 1 -4 2 -5 -5 -6 -3 -10 -3 -4 -1 -3 -1 -2 2 -4 -1 -3 -1 -9 0 -2 2 -4 3 0 -7 1 -4 -2 -2 0 -1 6 -3 6 -4 -1 -2 -2 -5 2 -3 4 -3 9 -1 10 1 9 2 9 -1 8 -1 9 -1 8 0 11 -1 z " />
          <path  id="CD11170" className="OUTLINE" d="M 394 349 l 3 1 4 1 2 -2 3 1 4 1 10 3 6 3 5 5 4 -2 3 -1 0 0 3 -1 2 1 1 0 2 -1 2 5 3 7 2 1 5 9 6 2 2 9 -4 5 -4 5 -5 6 -3 4 -5 4 -5 5 -5 4 -5 3 -8 8 -5 8 -7 3 -7 -1 -10 -4 -3 -1 -6 -3 -6 -5 -5 -3 -6 -3 -9 -3 1 -5 0 -10 -2 -8 -6 -11 5 -2 4 -1 5 -4 5 -6 2 -5 3 -6 6 -5 0 -3 -2 -3 4 -3 2 -2 z " />
  
          <text id="LCD11110" className="TEXT" x="399" y="277" >north</text>
          <text id="LCD11140" className="TEXT" x="433" y="338">middle</text>
          <text id="LCD11170" className="TEXT" x="407" y="395">south</text>    
</svg>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt1Vn.gif)

---

I want both to have the same Hoover effect....

⬇️ like this ⬇️

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20eJR.gif)

```html
<div id='wrap' class="back">
      <h3 class="box">north</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your CSS code too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to css for text `pointer-events:none;`

And then the color of the map will change when you hover over the letters too

```css
.OUTLINE {
fill:silver;
stroke:#000;
}
.OUTLINE:hover {
fill:orange;
}
.TEXT{
fill:#000;
pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<svg  viewbox="200 190 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path  id="CD11110" class="OUTLINE CD11110" d="M 455 297 l 4 -2 1 0 1 0 3 -1 4 5 7 3 2 6 0 8 -11 2 -11 1 -8 0 -9 1 -8 1 -9 1 -9 -2 -10 -1 -9 1 -4 3 -2 3 -6 -6 -3 -4 -5 -6 -4 -5 -2 -5 5 -3 0 -6 0 -10 0 -9 1 -9 -3 -4 -2 0 -2 0 -1 -4 0 -9 -5 -9 1 -10 -1 -11 -1 -6 2 -6 5 -2 7 -3 10 -2 2 -1 3 0 1 0 4 -2 8 -1 3 6 4 1 3 8 3 10 1 6 3 5 0 9 0 7 -1 5 -6 3 -6 4 -1 5 6 4 5 3 5 4 9 1 10 0 4 4 3 4 5 10 1 3 z " />
          <path  id="CD11140" class="OUTLINE" d="M 477 316 l 0 9 5 5 -1 3 -4 5 -4 5 -5 4 -4 7 -3 4 -4 3 -4 10 -2 -1 -3 -7 -2 -5 -2 1 -1 0 -2 -1 -3 1 0 0 -3 1 -4 2 -5 -5 -6 -3 -10 -3 -4 -1 -3 -1 -2 2 -4 -1 -3 -1 -9 0 -2 2 -4 3 0 -7 1 -4 -2 -2 0 -1 6 -3 6 -4 -1 -2 -2 -5 2 -3 4 -3 9 -1 10 1 9 2 9 -1 8 -1 9 -1 8 0 11 -1 z " />
          <path  id="CD11170" class="OUTLINE" d="M 394 349 l 3 1 4 1 2 -2 3 1 4 1 10 3 6 3 5 5 4 -2 3 -1 0 0 3 -1 2 1 1 0 2 -1 2 5 3 7 2 1 5 9 6 2 2 9 -4 5 -4 5 -5 6 -3 4 -5 4 -5 5 -5 4 -5 3 -8 8 -5 8 -7 3 -7 -1 -10 -4 -3 -1 -6 -3 -6 -5 -5 -3 -6 -3 -9 -3 1 -5 0 -10 -2 -8 -6 -11 5 -2 4 -1 5 -4 5 -6 2 -5 3 -6 6 -5 0 -3 -2 -3 4 -3 2 -2 z " />
  
          <text id="LCD11110" class="TEXT" x="399" y="277" >north</text>
          <text id="LCD11140" class="TEXT" x="433" y="338">middle</text>
          <text id="LCD11170" class="TEXT" x="407" y="395">south</text>    
</svg>
```